# R Studio read xlsx file, head() function doesn't display all the decimals of the values stored

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I am trying to read a scraped dataset stored in excel file. Once I loaded the file in RStudio, I checked the head(dataset, 5), but the columns of double values doesn't show full decimals, instead it shows:

```
100.
```

However, if I use View(dataset), it still shows the full decimals:

```
100.23
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
options(digits=10)
```

I have a picture here:
[image]

[image]

[image]
Is there anyway to solve it?

Comment: can you share your script

Comment: just did it, but according to neilfws, it was just the default setting..

Answer (score 2):

[This is just the default way](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-do-tibbles-and-data-frames-display-decimal-places-a-bit-differently/5722) in which the console prints a tibble. If you want to see the full values, you can use `print.data.frame`:

```
head(leipzig[, "Shot_x1"]) %>% 
  print.data.frame()
```

or better, since there is no need to `head()` a tibble:

```
leipzig %>%
  select(Shot_x1) %>%
  print.data.frame()
```